# npm install error (with shrinkwrap)

Tags: node.js, npm, openshift

i currently try to deploy a app on Openshift. Because of openshift use a old version of npm (not supporting ^ in version-number) i created a shrinkwrap.json file.

By running npm install on the Server i get:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!        
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0        
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-coffee@0.10.1 wants grunt@~0.4.0        
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-concat@0.3.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0        
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-copy@0.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0        
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.9.0 wants grunt@~0.4.1        
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jst@0.6.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0        
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-less@0.10.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0        
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-uglify@0.4.0 wants grunt@^0.4.0        
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-watch@0.5.3 wants grunt@~0.4.0
```

In my package.json i have:

```
"dependencies": {
   ....
   "grunt": "~0.4.5",
   ....
```

i cant change the dependencies of e.g. grunt-contrib-cssmin because they are dependencies from another package i have in my dependencies.

Anyone have a Idea to get this running?

Hints: Openshift runs npm v. 1.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend (if you are not able to change the `^` signs in your `package.json` file) is to commit to source control your dependencies and attempt to disable the `npm install` run by OpenShift.  The idea of checking in your dependencies in things you deploy is actually becoming more common, and avoids any of these deploy problems that you're seeing.  Here's a couple articles to convey my point:
http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html
https://www.npmjs.org/doc/faq.html#Should-I-check-my-node_modules-folder-into-git

But I assume you can not disable the `npm install`, which means you might try the following:

I'm not the most familiar with OpenShift, but might be able to at least point you in the right direction.  As I understand OpenShift, there are `action_hooks` which allow you to override (or at least take part in) the build and deploy steps.  There are some examples out there of this, here's one that I found: https://github.com/ramr/nodejs-custom-version-openshift/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/build

If it's not possible to *disable* the `npm install` run on your behalf, then perhaps you could hack around it by providing a fake `package.json` which you'd swap out prior to the build step, which would cause the `npm install` to be a no-op.  Not the best, but it might at least get you moving ahead.

Comment: You really made my day - thank you!

I only have to copy all files from https://github.com/ramr/nodejs-custom-version-openshift/blob/master/.openshift

So he install a freh version of npm an use this for deployment!

Comment: Keep in mind that some npm modules actually build binaries and may cause issues if you add your `node_modules` to git, as they will be platform dependent. Also, if you have a decent amount of modules, your repo will become HUGE.